# How do you extend the functionality of client.command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add to the handling of errors, args, kwargs and function stuff of `client.command`(`client` being a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance). 
Basically I'm trying to get all my commands to have certain custom behaviours in common.

My instant initial idea was to make a function that returns a decorator which decorates its wrapper with `client.command`.

However, the biggest problem I've encountered is that the parameter handling of the decorator returned by `client.command(...)` completely depends on the way the parameters and annotations of the decorated function are arranged, which means that a wrapper with its parameters like this

```py
async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
```

will receive arguments raw. That would mean I would have to handle everything myself inside the wrapper, which kind of defeats the whole point of using `discord.ext.commands` in the first place.

Reading [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), I tried to come up with a workaround. Here is a sketch of the code, with parts unrelated to the question cut out:

```py
from discord.ext import commands as c
import discord as d
client = c.Bot(command_prefix = "insert_prefix_here$")



def command(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        command_name = kwargs.setdefault("name", func.__name__)

        async def wrapper(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
            # do stuff with func and command_name

        # ...eh? this down here is the dirtiest thing i've ever seen
        wrapper.__defaults__ = func.__defaults__
        wrapper.__annotations__ = func.__annotations__

        wrapper = client.command(*args, **kwargs)(wrapper)


        @wrapper.error
        async def wrapper_error(ctx, error):
            # do stuff with ctx, error, command_name, ... etc

        return wrapper

    return decorator

# insert commands with @command(...) decorator here
```

I briefly thought of "tricking" the decorator returned by `client.command(...)` into thinking that the parameter structure of the wrapper is the same as the one of the decorated function by setting the wrapper's `__default__` and `__annotations__` attributes to those of the decorated function.

Yes, I am completely aware that's a horrible and not so well-thought idea (and it doesn't even work). That's why I posted this, it means my direction is no good.

Any suggestions?

Is there a much easier way of doing something like this that I was completely unaware of?

Should I just build a `command` decorator myself from scratch and stick with `discord.Client` instead of trying to add to `client.command`?

Comment: What exactly are the changes you want to make? It might be possible to subclass `Command` and pass your subclass to `client.command` with the `cls` argument.

Comment: To be more specific, right now I am trying to handle `BadArgument`, `MissingRequiredArgument`, the situation when another exception occurs and the situation when no exception occurs (and do something with the return value). **I want all commands to do it the same way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to extend the functionality of `Command` at all.  Instead, you can have bot-wide `on_command_error` and  `on_command_completion` events that provide the functionality you're looking for.

The only problem is the return value.  The easiest way is probably to assign an unused attribute of `ctx` instead of trying to capture a return value (You could also raise a custom error with the return value)

```
from discord.commands.ext import Bot, BadArgument, MissingRequiredArgument
import sys

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def some_command(ctx):
    ctx.return_value = 1

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That's a bad argument")
    elif isinstance(error, MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You're missing an argument")
    else:
        # This is what the standard on_command_error does
        print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(context.command), file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exception(type(exception), exception, exception.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

@bot.event
async def on_command_completion(ctx):
    await ctx.send(str(ctx.return_value))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```